# Cannot find module 'vue'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

Tags: vuejs3

I am trying to import any property
`import { ref } from 'vue'; import { onClickOutside } from '@vueuse/core';  import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';` 
from vue packages then i am getting this error.

`Cannot find module 'vue-router'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?` also for other objects i am getting this error `Property 'xxxxxx' does not exist on type '{}'.`

I have added `"moduleResolution":"node"` in compiler options then also i am getting same error.

How to ressolve this error??

Answer (score 10):

[This](https://blog.csdn.net/huchaoyue_/article/details/130745923) helped me

Add `"moduleResolution": "node"` to `"compilerOptions"` in `tsconfig.app.json` and restart VSCode

```json
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using vscode, try to change the typescript version of volar (workspace version). `command + p` and then search `volar`, you may see the option like this:

[change the typescript version of volar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhBIK.png)